# how to make the curve/points of the ggplot start from 0 line?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a small question regarding the ggplot, where in I want to know how to get the data points start with a 0 line without leaving that small gap on the left, right and the bottom.

This is my code:

```
hov.dat <- structure(list(x = c(3L, 3L, 9L, 25L, 25L, 27L, 30L, 39L, 49L, 
56L, 60L, 65L), y = c(55, 54, 34.33, 34, 75.66, 44, 56.55, 54, 
27.34, 30.75, 19.04, 25.29)), .Names = c("x", "y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))

with(hov.dat, plot(x, y))

qplot(x, y, data=hov.dat, geom=c('point', 'smooth'), method='lm', formula=y ~ ns(x, 3))
```

[image]

can anyone help me with what am I supposed to code to remove the left, right, and bottom gaps in the plot (marked with arrows in the picture)

Comment: Try `scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))` and corresponding for x axis

Comment: Unfortunately, this argument is not very thoroughly described in the help texts, I believe.

Comment: @Henrik, thanks for the help. I tried "scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))", but it does not change anything.. You are right, its not really described in the help texts.

Comment: Use `dput` on your data to produce runnable code. Don't paste the CSV into the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to supply the `expand` argument to `scale_x_continuous` (same for y-axis):

```
qplot(data=d,x,y,geom=c("point","smooth"),method="lm") + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
```

I could not execute function `ns`, so I didn't use your formula.

[image]

> expand: a numeric vector of length two giving multiplicative and
>          additive expansion constants. These constants ensure that the
>          data is placed some distance away from the axes.

Note that you can also extend the interpolation of your smoothing function, like in the following plot, which IMHO looks nicer. See [this question on CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36207/how-to-predict-or-extend-regression-lines-in-ggplot2):

```
gplot(hov.dat,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() + stat_smooth(method="lm",fullrange=T) + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-5,70),expand=c(0,0))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for this. I am still getting errors. Can you update the last line of my own code by putting in this argument, so that I can try it in the same way ?

Comment: @PoojaMandaviya Only if you provide a self-contained example. Your code relies on "example.csv"; I cannot test it. You should do this for every question if its feasible.